# Run time polymorphism Concept of OOPS

Tags: java, oop, interface, overriding, tostring

According to the concept of oops. In case of up casting reference variable of parent class can not execute the personal method of child class but when i run the following program-

```
interface My
{
}
class my1 implements My
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        My m=new my1();
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    }
}
```

it executes successfully and print "hello."
Can anyone explain how this is happening...??  
for to be more clear the following program gives compile time error

```
interface My
{
}
class my1 implements My
{
    public String toString1()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
       My m=new my1();
       System.out.println(m.toString1());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please link to where you read this.

Comment: OOPS does not provide casting rules. Secondly there is no superclass it is the interface. Thirdly an advice; you should read books.

Comment: Personal method???? What Rubbish......;(

Comment: @ankit Sharma-it means method of child class which are not present in parent class or interface..

Comment: Have you done any home work or refer some book/link to find out how polymorphism works, before post a question over here?